# Accessing SQL Server database from local network with .NET applications

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

A .NET application accessing a SQL Server 2017 database. When the database is on the local machine, all is well. However, when an instance of the application on a different computer within the local network attempts to connect, I get an error:

> The server was not found or was not accessible. verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Application details and connection string:

- WinForms app
- Targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1
- using `Sysetm.Data.SqlClient`

Connection string:

```
Server=localhost;Database=Retail_POS;User Id=sa;Password=sqlserver
```

This works on the local machine. It does not work on any other machine (with the IP address changed to that of the machine on which the database is located).

**Steps already taken**

SQL Server Configuration Manager:

- Made sure that TCP/IP protocol is enabled for correct instance of server.
- Right click TCP/IP protocol
- Select properties
- Click IP addresses tab
- Scroll down to IP4. Set active to yes and enabled to yes. Set TCP port to 1433
- Scroll down to IPAll. Set TCP port to 1433

SSMS:

- right click server instance, properties->connections-> allow remote connections. Security-> SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode
- restart the service

Comment: Have checked your firewalls?

Comment: No, I will do that and see.

Comment: @John followed these steps: https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-open-firewall-ports-in-windows-10,36451.html to no avail

Comment: please show the `connection string` for the `different computer`

Comment: Side note : please do avoid using `sa` for your application. Create a separate login for your application

Comment: @Squirrel connection string is: `"Server=192.168.1.102;Database=Retail_POS;User Id=sa;Password=sqlserver"`. The server address refers to the computer with the database running.

Comment: @Squirrel it has suddenly started working. This connection string works.